# Notificaciones en firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, android-service

Como puedo hacer para que la notificación firebase que llega mientras esta la pantalla apagada emita el sonido que tengo en mi carpeta raw. (si la app esta en primer plano el sonido se ejecuta sin problema)

Comment: El message entra a mostrarNotificacion() si la app esta en primer plano, pero cuando está en 2do plano es el mismo sistema quien la administra y por lo tanto no se puede personalizar el audio (.setSound). Cuál sería una posible solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Crear la clase MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mediaPlayer.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.uefa);
}}
```

**En el manifest.xml agregar**

```
   <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
```

**En la clase MyFireBaseMessagingService agregar**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
}
```

De esta forma cuando llega un mensaje se reproduce un sonido alertando que llego un mensaje aunque el telefono este con la pantalla apagada/cerremos la app

Answer (score 2):

Cuando envies la notificación ve a opciones avanzadas y habilita la prioridad y el sonido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda asignarle el sonido al Builder, esto si en el payload viene definido el sonido

```
 "sound" : "default"
```

la forma de asignar un sonido almacenado en el directorio `/raw` es la siguiente:

```
mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysound));
```

---

Asegura que en el payload venga el valor del sonido con el cual también puedes determinar reproducir o no el sonido:

> **[sound](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)**    (Opcional) Indica un sonido para reproducir cuando el dispositivo recibe la notificación. Admite default o el nombre de
>   archivo de un recurso de sonido contenido en la app.
>
> Los archivos de sonido de Android deben residir en /res/raw/, mientras
>   que los archivos de sonidos iOS se pueden encontrar en el contenido
>   principal de la app del cliente o en la carpeta Library/Sounds del
>   contenedor de datos de la app. Para obtener más información, consulta
>   la biblioteca para desarrolladores de iOS.

Answer (score 1):

La [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) indica que deberías usar este método:

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon",
      "sound" : "mySound"
    }
  }
```

y definir tu sonido en `"sound"` , si quisieras usar uno por defecto bastaría con poner `"sound": "default"`